# 2nd Activity won't open when Launching Activity is in Background

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have two relevant activities: `Main` and `ShowResult`. The 2nd one is launched from a Thread in `Main`. This works well, but as soon as `Main` is in background the activity won't open. Logcat doesn't show any anomalies.

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.....ShowResultActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com......MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Handler inside the Thread-class / executed from Thread:

```
iOpen = new Intent(context, ShowResultActivity.class); // is written in the constructor
Bundle b = new Bundle(); // global

b.putInt("type", 1);
b.putString("url", value);
iOpen.putExtras(b);
context.startActivity(iOpen);
```

ShowResult:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override 
public void  onNewIntent(Intent i) {
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    int value = b.getInt("type");
    String url = b.getString("url");

    Log.e("opened :)", value+" "+url);

    if(value == 0) {
        showPictureAsync(url);
    } else if (value == 1) {
        showVideoAsync(url);
    }

}
```

Comment: My guess: Your thread is killed before it can fire the activity. But to be sure: What exactly is in foreground, when the other one is in background?

Comment: No the thread is still active and responds to other things like playing music. Also it shows the url i want to pass.
It doesn't matter what is in foreground but for testing I used the stock Gallery.

Comment: Ok so you actually close the app itself (home button, back button, what ever)

Comment: The MainActivity is defined as launcher and everything is done, so it stays in the RAM. It is **not** destroyed, otherwise a method inside the thread would also be triggered which would destroy it. The actiivty just looses focus.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to use setContentView() in the ShowResult Activity and you see a black or black to blue gradient screen?

Comment: nope, it just doesn't show up, neither onCreate or onNewIntent is triggered

Comment: Okay i figured out that the MainAcitivity is in onStop state while doing this

Comment: It does not matter if MainActivity is onStop, if you follow my answer, it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
iOpen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(iOpen);
```

Comment: Really? I tested, I have just a simple activity with a button. For this button onClick I just make a new thread and sleep for 5 seconds and then launch the next activity. After I click the button, I press home. Without the flag nothing happens, but with the flag the second activity was launched after a few second.

Comment: I understand, what I am saying is maybe something else beside thread issue.

Comment: Normally it should throw an exception if so, but it doesn't

Comment: I don't know all I can add is my example is pretty simple. I just declare new Thread(new Runnable) and lauch the second activity inside the run() method after sleeping for 5 seconds. The only thing I can add is the context in this case is the first activity Activity1.this